# Color Histogram3D by Bin Location

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, histograms

I am using a `Histogram3D` plot to view the correlation of the R & G of an RGB image.  Naturally, I want the bins to have a color corresponding to their $x$, $y$ (R,G) position on the chart.

Unfortunately, `ColorFunction` for `Histogram3D` only supplies one argument, height, not $x$ or $y$ position.

Is there a way to color each bin based on its $x$ and $y$ position within the histogram? (i.e. `RGBColor[x,y,0]`)

Here is how I am generating my (uncolored) histogram:

```
    Histogram3D[Transpose[{
                           Flatten[ImageData[jpeg][[All,All,1]]]
                          ,Flatten[ImageData[jpeg][[All,All,2]]]
                           }]]
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I also want to make two other plots:

R,B: `RGBColor[x,0,y]` and
B,Y: `RGBColor[0,x,y]`

Comment: I'm not sure what that should show. For example `RGBColor[1, 1, 0]` is Yellow, but it doesn't mean it was Yellow in the image since you are not counting `Blue`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. I would like to display the color value without the `Blue` Counted.

Comment: You may be interested in my edit. I've also made your code more compact.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to ybeltukov I realised that post-processing way is not so bulletproof. Let's write a little bit longer solution to take control.

**`ChartElementFunction`**, is a handy way to deal with this (*only a little bit adapted example for documentation*):

```
f[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, {zmin_, zmax_}}, ___] := {
         RGBColor[Mean[{xmin, xmax}], Mean[{ymin, ymax}], 0], 
         Cuboid[{xmin, ymin, zmin}, {xmax, ymax, zmax}]}
```

And it works for small images too:

```
jpeg = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 5]

hist = Histogram3D[
                   Flatten[ImageData[jpeg][[;; , ;; , {1, 2}]], 1],
                   ChartElementFunction -> f]
```

(*I have changed a little bit your code to make it more compact*).

[image]

---

**Edit** All of the graphs you asked for. I had to modify `f` to make it more useful:

```
f[{x_, y_, z_}, ___, OptionsPattern[Irrelevant -> 1]] := {
               RGBColor @@ Insert[{Mean@x, Mean@y}, 0, OptionValue[Irrelevant]], 
               Cuboid @@ Transpose[{x, y, z}]}


jpeg = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Mandrill"}], 100]

Histogram3D[Flatten[ImageData[jpeg][[;; , ;; , #]], 1], PlotLabel -> #2,
            ChartElementFunction -> (f[##, Irrelevant -> "x"] & /. "x" -> #3)
           ] & @@@ {{{1, 2}, "R - G", 3}, 
                    {{1, 3}, "R - B", 2}, 
                    {{2, 3}, "G - B", 1}} // GraphicsRow[#, ImageSize -> 1000] &
```

[image]

---

**"Post-processing" way,** works automatically only for larger images, for small, take a look @ybeltukov solution.

`ChartElements` are `Cuboid` s. `r1` and `r2` are coordinates of oposite vertices. Just reffer the color to them as you like.  `r2 = {x2, y2, z2}` so you can involve height too.

To achieve what you've described in comments:

```
hist /. Cuboid[r1_, r2_] :> {RGBColor[##, 0] & @@ Most@(Mean /@ Transpose[{r1, r2}])
                             , Cuboid[r1, r2]}
```

[image]

Comment: @PerfectTommy does my edit fits your needs?

Comment: If you want this to work on small images add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` to `Histogram3D`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank's for the remark. `ChartElementFunction` has this advantage that it still creates tooltips for small images :)

Comment: @Kuba I ended up using the "post-processing" method and it worked wonderfully. Thanks!

Comment: @PerfectTommy I'm glad it helps :) good luck!

Answer (score 8):

Solution of Kuba works fine only for large images when bars on `Histogram3D` are not dynamic objects with tooltips. I provide more general solution

```
hist /. (h_ /; h === CuboidBox || h === Cuboid)[r1_, r2_] :> 
With[{col = Append[Most[r1 + r2]/2, 0]}, {RGBColor[col], h[r1, r2]} /; True])
```

For small data set there is `CuboidBox` instead of `Cuboid`. Moreover `CuboidBox` is in held expression so I use [Trott-Strzebonski](http://library.wolfram.com/conferences/devconf99/villegas/UnevaluatedExpressions/Links/index_lnk_30.html) in-place evaluation technique.

**Examples**

1. Small image

   ```
   jpeg = Image[RandomReal[1, {8, 12, 3}]]
   hist = Histogram3D[
      Transpose[{Flatten[ImageData[jpeg][[All, All, 1]]], 
        Flatten[ImageData[jpeg][[All, All, 2]]]}]];
   hist /. (h_ /; h === CuboidBox || h === Cuboid)[r1_, r2_] :> 
     With[{col = Append[Most[r1 + r2]/2, 0]}, {RGBColor[col], 
        h[r1, r2]} /; True]
   ```

   [image]
2. Large image

   ```
   jpeg = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"]
   hist = Histogram3D[
      Transpose[{Flatten[ImageData[jpeg][[All, All, 1]]], 
        Flatten[ImageData[jpeg][[All, All, 2]]]}]];
   hist /. (h_ /; h === CuboidBox || h === Cuboid)[r1_, r2_] :> 
     With[{col = Append[Most[r1 + r2]/2, 0]}, {RGBColor[col], 
        h[r1, r2]} /; True]
   ```

   [image]

Comment: One can add the option `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"` to `Histogram3D` to get the "large image" behavior on small data as well.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! I searched this option to no avail.

Comment: Without help from others (this site) or an almost pathological inclination for experimentation I don't know how one is to learn of such things.  I'm glad I could pass this information along.

Comment: @ybeltukov Good catch. I must admint I have not thought about this. Could you pleaste tell me why haven't you started to participate earlier in answering on this site? Looking on your answers I feel like we 'lost' a lot :)

Comment: p.s. Ok, I edited my post so it works with small images too :)

Comment: @Kuba Wonderful! I enjoy `ChartElementFunction`.